# Access to path denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, razor

I've uploaded my MVC Razor solution to my production server.

But when the website tried to access some files on my server (I've shared a folder and this is where the website reads files from) ... I get access denied.

I've tried to share the folder with "Everyone" permission and then it works fine.

My question is, which user should I add person for in the shared folder (using MVC 3 on an IIS7 server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can depend on how you have your configuration set up. But in the common scenario you need to look at the app pool your app is running in, and then find out the account that app pool is running under. That account is the one that should have permissions on the folder in question.